# How can I animate a set of moving point in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to build a simulator for some BOID objects, but I'm having some trouble with matplotlib's animation module (not helped by the very obtuse documentation). 
Here's the code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D #Import axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #Import plotting library
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np #Import numpy library

dim = 2             #Defines the dimensionality of the system
n = 6               #Number of BOIDS
tmax = 5             #Length of sim
o = np.zeros(dim) #Origin as vector
r = np.random.rand(n,dim) #Places BOIDs randomly with co-ordinates (x,y,z) from 0 to 1. Has dimensions n and dim
v = 2*np.random.rand(n,dim)-1#Sets initial velocity of each BOID from -1 to 1 in each cardinal direction
rt = np.zeros((tmax,n,dim)) #This array contains the whole system's positions at each point in time
x = np.empty(n)
y = np.empty(n)
"""rt[a]is r at t=a 
rt[a][b] is r array for t=a and n=b
 rt[0][a][b] is the x co-ordinate of boid n=b at t=a"""

fig = plt.figure() #Setting up a plotting figure for animation
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) #Establishes a subplot with axes
ax.grid(True,linestyle='-',color='0.75') #Sets up a grid on subplot
ax.set_xlim(-50,50)
ax.set_ylim(-50,50) #Set limits for x and y axes 


for t in range (0,tmax):
    for i in range (0,n):
        r[i] = r[i] + v[i]
        rt[t][i] = r[i]

def init():
    for i in range (0,n):
        x[i] = rt[0][0][i]
        y[i] = rt[1][0][i]
        print(i)
    return x,y,  

def update(j):
    for i in range (0,n):
        x[i] = rt[0][j][i]
        y[i] = rt[1][j][i]

    return x,y

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=tmax, init_func=init, interval=20, blit=True)
```

My problem is two-fold; Currently the code gives me this error:

```
x[i] = rt[0][0][i]
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

suggesting that I've mismatched the dimensions of the two array elements, but they should both just be a single number and not an array so I don't understand what's wrong.

Also, I don't really understand the need for the functions init and update. Can I not simply animate slices of rt instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to plot here. Hence its hard to help. `rt` has dimensions `(tmax,n,dim) == (5,6,2)`, hence the index of the last axis can only be 0 or 1, not 2. Either you don't want to loop over `range(n)` here but over `range(dim)`. Or you want to loop over `range(n)` but change the second index, not the third. Concerning the updating function, this should be used to plot something to the figure. "Simply animate slices of `rt`" would hence mean to call a plotting command inside the update function. (The init function may not actually be needed.) SO has enough examples.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, I did need to switch index to the second one. The init and update functions work as intended now I think. Are you saying I need to call some plotting function after defining x[i] and y[i] in the update function? Would that not create a new plot for each i instead of one animated plot?

Comment: You can either manipulate an existing plot inside that function or you can plot a new plot. That would depend on what you want to show and what kind of plot you have. But yes, you have one plot (how ever that is produced) per time step, which results in an animation - plot 1 at time step 1, plot 2 at timestep 2 etc. In how far do other examples you find not help?